# Links on my website are not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have a bootstrap website. At first, my links were concatenating (e.g. if I were to click on the home index page three times it would show instastatus.live/index.html/index.html/index.html) every time I clicked a link.

The issue has been solved, but now the link won't go through. For example, if I click one of the nav bar items such as "Services", the URL shows the correct address: instastatus.live/services/index.html. However, it won't go to the page until I click on the URL bar and hit enter (only then will it take me to the appropriate page). Otherwise, it does nothing.

```
<nav class="cb-navbar">
    <div class="cb-container">
      <div class="cb-navbar-inner">
        <div class="cb-navbar-left">
          <a href="index.html" class="cb-navbar-back">
            <i class="cb-icon -long-arrow-left"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" class="cb-navbar-logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cb-navbar-right">
          <div class="cb-navbar-nav">
            <a href="/services/index.html" id="navbar-services" class="cb-navbar-nav-item">
                    <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-icon">
                        <i class="cb-icon -cog"></i>
                    </span>
              <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-text">Services</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/projects/index.html" id="navbar-projects" class="cb-navbar-nav-item">
                    <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-icon">
                        <i class="cb-icon -bars"></i>
                    </span>
              <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-text">Projects</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/contacts/index.html" onclick="yaCounter.reachGoal('contacts')" id="navbar-contacts" class="cb-navbar-nav-item">
                    <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-icon">
                        <i class="cb-icon -contacts"></i>
                    </span>
              <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-text">Contacts</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: instastatus.live/services/index.html ? it's working.

Comment: Yes the url works. However, when you click a navbar item from the home page, you need to either hit refresh or click the address bar and hit enter to go the page.

Comment: Are you possibly using a return false anywhere in onClick or somewhere

Comment: I guess the script `yaCounter.reachGoal('...')` inside your `onclick` handler is possibly returning nothing (or `undefined`) which is evaluated as a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value and thus navigation is prevented

Comment: try adding `yaCounter.reachGoal('...') || true` which will always evaluate to true